# Entity Framework - Link Table Representation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am new to Entity Framework. I am using database first approach and I don't auto generate entity files. I have 3 tables `User`, `Database` and `UserDatabase`. The table `UserDatabase` has a many-to-many relationship with both `User` and `Database`. I am not sure how to build this relationship in my class.

```
public class Database
{
    [Key]
    public int DatabaseId { get; set; }

    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int? UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class UserDatabase
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User Users{ get; set; }

    public int DatabaseID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DatabaseID")]
    public virtual Database Database { get; set; }
}
```

This is my current code. If I add one database per user it is working fine. But if I add multiple, it throws multiplicity constraint violation error. Please help.

Comment: So one user can have many databases? Should UserDatabase.Database be a List<Database>?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the mistake. In the link table "UserDatabase" I have mentioned UserID as the primary key and that is why I am not able to add multiple records. It should be a composite key and I have marked both user and database as key and given the order. I have changed it to

```
public class UserDatabase
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User Users{ get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public int DatabaseID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DatabaseID")]
    public virtual Database Database { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your `UserDatabase` to following:

```
public class UserDatabase
{
    [ForeignKey("Users")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Database")]
    public int DatabaseID { get; set; }

    public virtual User Users{ get; set; }
    public virtual Database Database { get; set; }
}
```